# what is the preferred way to add Vue plugins ( ui elements that use the form vue.use() ) to the vue-storefront code base?

Tags: vue-storefront

Hey guys what is the preferred way to add Vue plugins (UI elements that use the form vue.use() ) to the code base ?

As per the documentation ( https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/core-themes/plugins.html#theme-plugins ) I added the following code to /src/themes/defaultx/plugins/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted'
Vue.use(Toasted)
```

But it doesn't register my plugin and throws undefined when trying to use it.

I tried placing Vue.use() in themes/index.js where Vue.use(processbar) lives but placing it there (or anywhere else where Vue is imported) starts throwing "document/window not found" errors.

I have tried two libraries vue-notification and vue-toasted

P.S. ( defaultx is a just a simple copy of default )

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are some parts missing in docs.

Theme index is actually the right place but the error is caused by SSR Mode. You need to invoke Vue.use only on client side (you can either use `Vue.prototype.$isServer` or check if `window !== 'undefined'`)